# Server.Transfer cannot render an MVC-View

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, http-status-code-404, application-error

In my Application_Error event handler i want to render an MVC-View for 404. I do not want to redirect because of SEO.

```
void Application_Error(...)
{
 if (serverException is HttpException && ((HttpException)serverException).GetHttpCode() == 404)
 {
  Server.Transfer("/error/404"); //*
 }
}
```

//* Fails, because it cannot find the path on disk. Of course not because it should be handled by MVC.

**How to render an MVC-View from Application_Error?**

I do not want to redirect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just don't use Application_Error to handle 404 errors. Define a catch all route:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "Error", 
    "{*url}", 
    new { controller = "Error", action = "Http404" });
```

A request that doesn't match another route will be handled by the `Http404` action of the `Error` controller.

Comment: I am still using Webforms. I want a catch all solution that works for _any_ 404 sent to the client.